# Rpm-spec file. running yum groupinstall

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm

Good afternoon,

I am currently building an RPM that has some requirements I have not found answers to on the web. I have narrowed this down to a single question.

Normally when I run an install from command line, one of the steps has me run the following command `yum groupinstall "Compatibility libraries"` which installs 32-bit compatibility libraries on my 64-bit desktop. I am wondering if there is a way to accomplish this in the **`Requires:`** field of my RPM-spec file, as I have only found a way to require very specific RPM's for dependencies?

I could always add in the 10-15 individual packages that get installed with `yum groupinstall "Compatibility Libraries"`, but I was hoping there was a better option.

Description of RPM:
My RPM is very basic in nature. It will untar multiple tar files into various locations, overwrite files throughout the main install directory, install compatibility libraries, and then proceed to startup a service.

If anyone needs more information to what I am trying to accomplish please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can only require specific packages, not groups, in your `Requires:` lines.  You should absolutely not run `yum` in your `%post` script, because then (a) you are then hiding your dependencies, and nobody likes to see things get installed that they didn't expect, and (b) you will probably end up getting stuck because `yum` in `%post` would need to wait for the existing yum process to exit.

For *library* `Requires:`, the rpm build process will generally figure things out for you.  You still need to manually specify the appropriate `BuildRequires:` dependencies, which are things that are required to *build* the package.

If you want to update your question with more details (e.g., a link to the spec file and a description of what you're trying to do, if it's not obvious from the spec), maybe we can come up with better solutions.

Comment: Hmm, what you have written pretty much solidifies my knowledge. From what I have gathered, it would be best to include a `%pre` section to my RPM which would install the "Compatibility Libraries". You mentioned that `yum` in `%post` would probably get stuck waiting on the first yum. Is there a way to overcome this that you can think of?

Comment: To clarify, my RPM would lay down a couple tar files, install compat libraries, and then startup several processes. I cannot post my spec file. I can accomplish everything but installing my compatibility libraries via this rpm already

Comment: this would work perfectly if I could install the "Compatibility Libraries" inside of the `Requires: section of the spec file.